# Using Jquery to return elements of XML string doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Using jQuery I use the selector and the each function to itterate through named elements of an XML string.

e.g.

```
$("<xml><elem></elem><elem></elem></xml>").each(function() 
{ 
   alert("processing elem tag");
});
```

This works fine in FF/Chrome/IE<8 but in 9 fails. Presumably something in the IE doc no longer allows this.

Comment: I'm having same issue for IE8, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not intended to take a string of XML directly, only from an AJAX response, e.g. `.responseXML`, in any case don't worry about it *at this point*.

IE9 has bugs, it's not RTM quality, they are mostly *their* bugs...I personally wouldn't waste time changing (or even debugging) *your* code until their's is more complete/stable.  (Opinion) don't worry about the client with IE9 either...they signed on for a buggy experience when they installed pre-release software.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't parse XML. What `$("<xml><elem></elem><elem></elem></xml>")` does is to create an element and set its `innerHTML` property to `"<xml><elem></elem><elem></elem></xml>"`, which will have variable and unpredictable results.

You need to parse the XML using the browser's built-in XML parser. Here's a function that does this. I haven't tested it in IE 9 but I'd be surprised if it didn't work: [they've implemented DOMParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta), so unlike IE < 9 it will fall into the first branch and should work unless they've made a mess of it.

```
var parseXml;

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
       return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}

var xmlStr = "<xml><elem></elem><elem></elem></xml>";
var xmlDoc = parseXml(xmlStr);

$(xmlDoc).each(function() { 
   alert("processing elem tag");
});
```

Comment: In IE8 it's showing blank object `[object] { }`. Is it still working in IE8? `window.DOMParser` is undefined for IE 8.

Comment: I've post new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895014/not-able-to-load-xml-file-in-ie8 here if you could help me. Thanks!