# Not able to load xml file in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to find the solution to load xml file and retrieve element value by tag name but stuck at the final step. Code is working in all other modern browsers **except IE8**.

```
function getXML(xmlStr) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
       alert("window.DOMParser");
       return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
       alert("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       xmlDoc.async = "false";
       xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
       alert("xmlDoc");
       return xmlDoc;
    } else {
       return null;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var xmlStr = "<xml><elem>element1</elem><elem>element2</elem></xml>";
  var xmlDoc = getXML(xmlStr);
  $("#result").html("<b>Elemtent:</b> " + JSON.stringify(xmlDoc) + "<br/><br>");
});
```

I've created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mynk28/tuxpu4aq/3/) here which is the modification of the actual post answer by [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213640/using-jquery-to-return-elements-of-xml-string-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer).

I've tried many ways but no luck at all. Is it possible to load xml and get values in IE8?

Comment: Have you tried to catch the error thrown by IE8? Also, since you're using jQuery already, why not use `$.parseXML(xmlStr)` rather than `loadXML`?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors.

Comment: IE8 is not a modern browser, it's ancient, and is no longer supported by Microsoft.  IE8 doesn't support `window.DOMParser`, and I suspect that if Active X is disabled (which it is by default) then the `getXML` function will just return null.  I'd suggest you just drop support for IE8.

Comment: See the yellow note halfway down about IE security settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the help, I fixed the issue myself. Thanks again!